# If a force is applied tangent to the edge of a Cylinder in SPACE will it move forward or just spin in place?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Like if there is a force on the edge then how will the torque and the force on the cylinder produce the subsequent motion?

Comment: The centre of mass of the cylinder will always undergo a translational acceleration under the action of the external force. If the line of action of the external force does not go through the centre of mass of the cylinder then there will be a torque acting on the cylinder about its centre of mass and it will also undergo an angular acceleration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The sum of all external forces is related to the acceleration of the center of mass.
2. The sum of all torques is related to the angular acceleration.

Hence it only spins on itself if the sum of all forces is zero (but the sum of all torques isn't). If you pull on one side, you need to push on the other to keep the cylinder in place while spinning it.

Imagine a cylinder floating in space. If you pull on one side, it will spin and move towards you at the same time.